# Struts2 - Isolating WebContents from Back-end Logic

Tags: java, struts2

I am totally new to Struts2 framework (and Java web services), and just went through few tutorials.

I have a general question here, in most tutorials, web contents like pages and back-end logic are stored in one single war package.

If I would need to make some quick changes to the pages (small ones, like updating text or picture), seems like I would need to deploy the war package again (according to the hello world tutorials).

In real life web applications, is there a better way to apply quick web page changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a CMS, not a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.

There are companies using a [Continuous Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) approach, that allows them to release in production in *minutes*. For this lucky guys, it's not a problem.

Other companies are uglily drowned in burocracy, and every release means time, money and documentation, and hence this should be handled carefully.

Since **JSP**s (and **Facelets**) are not simple views but contain logic (not serverside logic like in the dark **scriptlets** days, but presentation logic), they should be part of a release process. Then you should keep them in the usual WAR, and extract from it only the pure presentation files, referencing them externally: **.css**, **.js**, **images**, **HTML** files and so on.

This way, if you will need to change the company logo, or the background color, you won't need to release anything except the static resources, if instead you'll need to add a new functionality, this will imply a release process.

This discussion can change with recent front-end frameworks (AngularJS, React, etc...) because **HTML** and **.js** there are part of the business logic. In those case, I'd take out just **.css** and **images**, keeping the rest under release control.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrea. As mentioned, I am really new to the Java web world, your answer helped a lot.